# AngularJS 1.5: Link not working

Tags: angularjs, html

I have a link in the page home.thml to another page comments.html

```
<a href='#/comments'>See the comments</a>
```

I develop this code in the page home.html

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
            $routeProvider
                .when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'})
                .when('/comments', {templateUrl: 'partials/comments.html'})
                .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
        });
```

I don't know where is the mistake. Help me.

Thank you

Comment: Do you get any error in console window?

Comment: @ImmanuelKirubaharanS No

Comment: Are you sure that you've injected **ui.router** in your module?

Comment: i think it should be ui-href=""

Comment: @ImmanuelKirubaharanS he clearly uses **ngRoute**, also the hash-bang could be `#!/` and not `#/`

Comment: @ImmanuelKirubaharanS
Yes, I injected it.
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.6/angular-animate.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.6/angular-route.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  var app = angular.module('formation',['ngAnimate','ngRoute']);
  app.config(function($routeProvider){
   $routeProvider
    .when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'})
    .when('/comments', {templateUrl: 'partials/comments.html'})
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
  });

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Your proposition is working, thank you so much :)

Comment: I think your hash-bang was `projectAngularJS`, you messed up your routing somewhere

Comment: projectAngularJS is the name of my project folder. I use Wamp Server

Answer (score 0):

After version 1.4.6 (I believe) the hashbang as they call, used to change routes changed from `#/` to `#!`.

To access specific routes you need to do `href="#!/route1"`.

To access root page again, it would be `href="#/!"` (Not the change of `!` placement.)